# Get a list of instances from aws via cli containing ID - tag instance name, and detailed OS information

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, command-line-interface, aws-cli

Get a list of instances from aws via cli containing ID - tag instance name, and detailed OS information.

Hello, I need help getting a list of instances in aws via cli containing ID - tag instance name, and detailed OS information.

What I've already tried:

aws ssm describe-instance-information --query 'InstanceInformationList[*].[InstanceId,PlatformType,PlatformName]' --output table --region us-east-1

[image]

If I run it this way using AWS SSM, I have the information I need but I don't have the value of the instance name tag - if I try to add it, it returns null.

aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{PublicIP:PublicIpAddress,PrivateIP:PrivateIpAddress,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,Type:InstanceType ,Status:State.Name,VpcId:VpcId,PlatformType,PlatformName}" --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --output table

[image]

Executing this way I have the value of the name tag but I don't have the information I need to detail the operating system.

How to "unify" both commands so that I have the information I need in a single table? InstanceID, InstanceName, PlatformType and PlatformName.

The intent is to get a list of VMs with detailed operating system information.

Comment: please don't paste text as screenshots.  Copy the text and paste as text, delineated by triple-backtick ```

Comment: "How to "unify" both commands so that I have the information I need in a single table? InstanceID, InstanceName, PlatformType and PlatformName."   You can generate the output of both commands and then use [`join`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) to join them if you want to work in bash / unix.  I personally would write a quick little script or program  if bash/unix isn't your thing.